# HTML / VUE - Allow user to select/activate multiple <input> elements and type in them at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a HTML table with 2 columns that looks like this:

```
Item       Amount
Icecream   $3
Hotdog     $5
Hamburger  $10
```

The "amount" column consists of `<input>` elements that live in a `<td>`

The user should be able to select the $3 field, (hold down control?) and then also select the $5 field, then type in $6 , causing the $3 and the $5 to be changed to $6.
I understand this is kind of 2 questions. I think once i know how to let the user select multiple inputs I will be able to figure out the typing part. I'm using Vue in case that helps

Answer (score 1):

You must do a few things to achieve that:

1. Listen to on click event, which is fairly easy in vuejs

```html
<element @click="firstWay"/> // this will pass only the `$event` as an argument
<element @click="$event => secondWay($event, someOtherProperty)"/> // and this way, you can define your own arguments
```

```js
methods: {
  firstWay ($event) { },
  secondWay ($event, someOtherProperty) {}
}
```

2. Know when ctrl key is pressed (`event.ctrlKey` is there for you)
3. Keep track of selected items - using your data object.

### Example

#### Template

```html
    <tr
      v-for="(item, idx) in items"
      :key="idx"
    >
      <td v-text="item.name"/>
      <td>
        <input
          type="number"
          :value="item.price"
          step="0.01"
          :selected="item.selected"
          @click="$event => onClick($event, item)"
          @input="$event => onInput($event, item)"
        />
      </td>
    </tr>
```

#### JavaScript

```js
  data: {
    items: [
        { name: 'Icecream',     price: 3.14, selected: false },
        { name: 'Hotdog',       price: 6.00, selected: false },
        { name: 'Hamburger',    price: 2.00, selected: false }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    onClick (event, item) {
      if (event.ctrlKey) {
        item.selected = !item.selected
      }
    },

    onInput (event, item) {
      const value = event.target.value
      item.price = value

      if (!item.selected) return

      this.items
        .filter(it => it.selected)
        .forEach(it => {
            it.price = value
        })
    }
  }
```

#### Styles

```css
input[selected] {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

[Here you play with working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/uxs7mkhb/8/)

Comment: wow thank you for such a thorough answer. I'm on the fiddle now and am unable to select multiple HTML holding down Control. I'm on a mac using Chrome. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You should be able to select multiple inputs by clicking on them while holding ctrl key. I've just tested it on chrome (linux-83.0.4103.61), firefox (linux - 68.8.0esr) and opera (windows-68.0.3618.125), i don't have any Mac rn. Perhaps the outline styles are being overridden by your browser. Is it only graphical issue, or the input logic is not working as well?

Comment: when i click on an input holding the control key a pop up appears with options such as copy / paste

Comment: Looks like some binding which is specific to your browser (or it's plugin?), os, etc. Perhaps using [Event#preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) and / or [Event#stopImmediatePropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation) will help. Check [this version of a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6t051epx/1/).

Comment: unfortunately I'm still just getting the pop up! Can you try it with holding down shift instead maybe?